# Input lags when layout switch with Super+Space

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, gnome-shell, input

After update to Ubuntu 17.10 I catch a new very annoying bug. My shortcut to switch keyboard layouts is "super+space". After the switch, I have input delay and loss 1-3 first letters. With "Ctrl+Shift" I don't have this problem but cannot use it for another bug. Which way should I check to resolve this?